# VS Code Duplicate Path Suggestions

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am currently using VS Code for a Node.js project and I have the [Path Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense)
 extension installed, however I seem to be getting duplicate file suggestions. Is there any way to limit it to only one suggestion?

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did anyone find an answer to this question? I am also having the same issue.

Comment: @MananJoshi I haven't found a solution, my laptop seems to work fine but the desktop still exhibits this behaviour. Its very strange. Its not a terrible problem but still annoying.

Comment: I actually found a solution to this issue. Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63095724/duplicate-import-suggestions-in-vs-code?noredirect=1#comment111575460_63095724

Comment: @MananJoshi I seem to now get duplicates, fixed the `../../..` but now I get duplicate files/folders

Comment: Do you mind sharing a screenshot? I do remember facing this issue just wanted to make sure if it is the same thing that I am thinking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable two settings:

1. `"javascript.suggest.paths": false` [source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/92101#issuecomment-595841556)
2. `"node-module-intellisense.scanFileModules": false` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63096590/8095383)

Thank you [Manan Joshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5266912/manan-joshi) for your assistance.

Optional:
You can also disable `"typescript.suggest.paths": false` (if you are using TypeScript)