# Duplicate import suggestions in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

### Recently I am being shown duplicate suggestions like this

[image: Duplicate suggestions image]

---

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: 1st option is the folder name... 2nd is the folder path/your input? Doesn't look like an issue.

Comment: It did not show like this earlier, I guess some settings have updated. It only showed the directory and not the entire path.

Comment: You seem to have two or more path intellisense extensions

Answer (score 3):

So actually I figured out the issue. If you have installed both [Path Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense) and [Node Module Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=leizongmin.node-module-intellisense) extensions, both will search for all the modules in the project and hence resulting in duplicates showing up. The way to solve this issue is to add the following to **settings.json**

```
"node-module-intellisense.scanFileModules": false
```

Comment: Thanks this solution works. I had two plugins Path Intellisense and Path Autocomplete enabled. Disabled path Autocomplete fixed it.