# How to configure VSCode to autocomplete image paths in React?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio

My VSCode doesn't autocomplete image paths when using React. Folders and .js files work fine. I try using a few extensions but now the folder/js files are duplicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install [path-intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense) in VSCode. Autocompleting paths should not be modifying or duplicating anything.

Comment: I tried the extension. I can see the files path but folders are being duplicated: https://imgur.com/8XRc2Kx

Comment: Do you possibly have other, similar extensions installed? If not, this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60850287/vs-code-duplicate-path-suggestions